# Why is my list comprehension not showing same result as the for loops?

Tags: python, sum, list-comprehension, triplet

Below is my code to triplets that sums to a give value (using for loop)

```
def triplet(array,num):
     for a in range(len(array)):
        for b in range(a):
            for c in range(b):
                if array[a]+array[b]+array[c]==num:
                    print(array[a],array[b],array[c])

triplet([6,5,4,7,3,12],15)
```

Result is below(as expected)

```
(4, 5, 6)
(3, 7, 5)
```

However, if I change the code to use list comprehension (as below), result is incorrect. Why??

```
def triplet(array,num):
    for a in range(len(array)):
        print [(a,b,c) for a in range(len(array)) for b in range(a) for c in range(b) if array[a]+array[b]+array[c]==num]
triplet([6,5,4,7,3,12],15)
```

Result for the above code is as below

```
[(2, 1, 0), (4, 3, 1)]
```

Comment: You are printing `a,b,c` in your list comprehension . these are the indexes in your origina list.. notice that in the first loop you do `array[a], array[b]...` and in your list comprehension you just do `a,b..`

Comment: Are you intentionally not allowing repeated values? For example, `(5, 5, 5)` or `(3, 6, 6)`

Answer (score 0):

In your list comprehension, you put `(a,b,c)` instead of `(array[a],array[b],array[c])`. Moreover you do not need the for loop before the print statement, because it is already included in the comprehension. So you can write as follows:

```
def triplet(array,num):
    print([(array[a],array[b],array[c]) for a in range(len(array)) for b in range(a) for c in range(b) if array[a]+array[b]+array[c]==num])

triplet([6,5,4,7,3,12],15)  # [(4, 5, 6), (3, 7, 5)]
```